# Angular form showing before properly populating, how do I wait for a for loop to finish?

Tags: angular, reactive

I have an Angular application where I'm getting data from an API and populating a reactive form.  Hopefully the following code is self explanatory.

The complication is that a quote has QuoteItems which have QuoteLineItems.

```
this.quoteService.get(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
.subscribe(
  result => {
    this.quote = result;

    this.quoteForm = this.fb.group({
      quoteBy: new FormControl({ value: this.quote.quoteBy, disabled: true }),
      design: new FormControl({ value: this.quote.design, disabled: true }),
      quoteV2Items: this.fb.array([]),
    });

    for (const element of this.quote.quoteItems) {
      this.quoteItems.push(this.fb.group({
        quoteItemId: element.quoteItemId,
        itemNumber: element.itemNumber,
        location: element.location,
        quoteLineItems: this.fb.array([]),
      }));
      for (const element2 of element.quoteLineItems) {
        this.quoteLineItems(this.quote.quoteItems.indexOf(element)).push(this.fb.group({
          quoteLineItemId: element2.quoteLineItemId,
          description: element2.description,
          rate: element2.rate,
          quantity: element2.quantity,
          total: element2.total,
        }));
      }
    }

    this.loading = false;

  },
  error => {
    this.loading = false;
  }
);

get quoteItems() {
  return this.quoteForm.get('quoteItems') as FormArray;
}

quoteV2LineItems(index) {
  return (this.quoteForm.get('quoteItems') as FormArray).at(index).get('quoteLineItems') as FormArray
}
```

The problem is that 1 out of every 3 times when I go to the page, I think the form is being shown before it's populated and the page doesn't render properly.  I suspect I can fix this by making sure the for loop completes before I set loading to true - how can I do this?

Update, actually I'm sure this is the issue, if I have a large object then every refresh has different amounts of the nested objects populated.

Update: This is the html:

```
<form [formGroup]="quoteForm" autocomplete="off">
    <input matInput formControlName="quoteBy">
    <input matInput formControlName="design">
    <div formArrayName="quoteItems" *ngIf="quoteItems && quoteItems.length > 0">
        <div *ngFor="let controls of quoteItems.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            {{controls.get('itemNumber').value}}
            {{controls.get('location').value}}
            <ng-container>
                <div formArrayName="quoteLineItems"
                    *ngFor="let controls of quoteLineItems(i).controls;let j=index" [formGroupName]="j">

                    {{controls.get('description').value}}
                    {{controls.get('rate').value | currency}}
                    {{controls.get('quantity').value}}
                    {{controls.get('total').value | currency}}
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML template where you are showing your form?

Comment: Sure, done @ZetaPR

Comment: `<form [formGroup]="quoteForm" *ngIf="quoteForm else #loading">...</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should controll if you want to show or not the form once you know if the `this.quote` is filled.
I would suggest adding to check if the quoteForm and you have finished loading

> `*ngIf="quoteForm && !loading"`  this should be added to
> `<form [formGroup]="quoteForm" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: Thank you however this did not fix it - I actually have that *ngIf on a parent div, just didn't include it in the code sample

Comment: Then just create a new variable and until the form is not finished don't set it to true. This way you make sure is finished populating.